# Selecting ActiveRecord objects by attribute value of associated AR object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Given an ActiveRecord class (e.g. Posts) that is associated to another ActiveRecord class (e.g. Tags), how can I select only those Posts, who are associated to a Tag with a certain attribute value (e.g. Tag.name="Music").

Up to now I defined a class method on Posts like that:

```
def self.tag_filter(tag_name, posts)
  unless tag_name == '' || posts == nil
    postlist = posts
    posts = []
    postlist.all.each do |post|
      post.tags.each do |tag|
        if tag.name == tag_name 
          posts<<post
        end
      end
    end
  end
  posts
end
```

To use it in the controller like this:

```
def posts_filter
  @user = current_user
  @posts = @user.posts

  tag_filtered_posts = Post.tag_filter(params[:tag_select], @posts)
  ..
end
```

But that didn't feel right from start and somehow I feel that this should be much easier to implement. What am I missing?

Comment: What is the relation between posts and tags?

Comment: It's a has_and_belongs_to_many relation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [joins](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) method:

```
Post.joins(:tags).where(tags: { name: tag_name })
```

Comment: Will this also work on an association relation object like @user.posts?

Comment: I think this will work: `User.joins(posts: :tags).where(tags: {  name: tag_name })`

Comment: I did this now and it seems to work: `user.posts.joins(:tags).where(tags: { name: "default" })`